# Can't handle Reactjs infinite-react-carousel error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, carousel

I'm trying to use a infinite-react-carousel in my project. I did steps described in npm documentation but getting error.
Here is the example of simple Carousel.[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from 'infinite-react-carousel';

const Carousel = () => (
    <Slider dots>
        <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
        </div>
    </Slider>
);

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: This problem is hidden in their module. It was connected with incapsulation of modules

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this, this solution worked for me:

```js
const [sliderVisible, setSliderVisible] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  setSliderVisible(true);
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    {sliderVisible &&
      <Slider>
        ...slides
      </Slider>
     }
  </div>
);
```

For some reason the slider component doesn't like being loaded immediately. I was having an issue where it would cause a crash if the page was reloaded with the slider on the screen, throwing the same error as OP.